# iPhone Facebook / Linkedin Home Screen Widget

Tags: iphone, facebook

Can anyone explain how facebook and linkedin implemented the home screen widget for their iphone applications?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the "launcher" style view that behaves and looks the same as the iPhone's homescreen with the app icons, then you can use Three20's `TTLauncherView`.

Check out http://three20.info