# Programming an app similar in appearance to the Facebook app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm programming an iPhone application. This application contains a home page, which I would like to be almost the same as the one in facebook for iPhone : rows of icons, each icon corresponding to a category of my application.

I'm a newbie in iPhone development, and I can't find which control is used to show this view. Could someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Facebook / Linkedin Home Screen Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288100/iphone-facebook-linkedin-home-screen-widget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best bet is to use [Three20](http://three20.info/) library - it is opensource and it is the framework that was used to create an original facebook app.  There is a bunch of controls in the framework, TTLauncherView is your friend to create a homescreen.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm gonna play with it